# Suppose $f \in L^1$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \int_{-n}^{n} fdx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces

Suppose that $f \in L^1$. Show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2n} \int_{-n}^{n} fdx = 0$$

I have an idea here. I believe I want to show that $\int_{-n}^{n} f dx$ is finite. If it is finite, then taking the limit will give me the desired $0$.

In terms of how to do this, I'm thinking about what I know so far. I know $f \in L^1$. The definition we were given of $L^1$ is that $f$ is measurable such that $\int |f| < \infty$. So I know the integral of the absolute value is finite, but it doesn't state that the integral of $f$ is finite. So I'm not fully sure I can make this conclusion. Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more point to make is that $f\in L^1$ implies $\int f <\infty$.
To see this we note that $E_+=\{x:f(x) \geq 0\}$ and $E_-=\{x:f(x)<0\}$ are both measurable sets set $f_+=f \chi_{E_+}, f_-=f \chi_{E_-}$ then $f=f_+ +f_-$ and $|f|=f_+ -f_-$
Since $\int |f| < \infty \implies \int f_+, \int f_-<\infty$ which will imply $\int f <\infty$

We have the condition that $\int f<\infty \iff \int |f|<\infty$

The reason we characterize $L^1$ in terms of $|f|$ is to ensure that we get a norm on our linear space.

Also, one thing to keep in mind is that $f\in L^1$ is not actually a function but a set of functions (equivalence class) the equivalence being defined by equal up to sets of measure zero

$f$~$g \iff \mu(\{x: f(x)\neq g(x)\})=0$ .

Comment: This is what I wanted to see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $b_n=\int_{-n}^nfdx$. We have that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-n}^nfdx=C \in (-\infty,\infty)$ because $f \in L^1$. We then have that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n=0\cdot C=0$$

Comment: Why is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-n}^{n} f dx = C$? That is the fact I was unsure about. We did not prove that in my class, so that is why I didn't know if the fact was true. It's obvious if that fact is true. Could you prove that?

Comment: By definition of f being $L^1$, ...